# VBA Hyperlink: How to select the row of the target cell and centering it in the center of the screen

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

After clicking a hyperlink and arriving at a target cell, I want to select (highlight) the entire row of the target cell and scroll so that the target cell is around the middle column of the screen and about 5 columns to its right are shown. I wrote FollowHyperlink() after the working hyperlink code. The code has no error but does not do anything..

```
Sub CreateHyperlink()
...
If i > 1 Then
    .Hyperlinks.Add ...
End If
End Sub    

Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)

ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = ActiveCell.Column
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Would you mean to use `Target.EntireRow.Select`?  This also assumes all links are on the same worksheet as the trigger, is that correct?

Comment: @BruceWayne Yes to both of your questions. Changed ActiveCell to Target, but the same result as of now.